# Airflow - Is it possible to delete the xcom key-value pairs only for the current dag run?

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I need to run a DAG every 10 minutes. Sometimes a DAG starts (run2) run and the previous running(run1) is still in "running" state.

My problem is related with xcom deletes. If run2 finishes first (because the batch of data is lighter for example) it will delete all xcom from that dag_id, so the xcom from the run1 ( that is still running) will be deleted in the middle of DAG process.

How can I delete only the xcom from the self DAG? I mean, delete only the xcom created in run2 but keep the xcoms created on run1.

PS:I tried to use max_active_runs=1 but they make a "wait queue" and I don't want it.

Thanks a lot all.

```
delete_xcom_task = PostgresOperator(
      task_id='delete-xcom-task',
      postgres_conn_id='postgres',
      sql="delete from public.xcom where dag_id='dag_id'",
      dag=curation)
```

Comment: How do you know the xcom is deleted? It should not be - Xcom should only be deleted for the specific dag run id. This is different for retries (same dagrun id) - there retries will delete the xcom. Similarly if you clear and bckfill the runs. But for different run ids Airflow should not delete xcoms.

Comment: As you said the xcom is deleted because that task showed above will delete all data created from dag_id dag... dag_id here is an example....my dag name is xcom_exercise_dag

Comment: Why do you want to delete the xcom this way ?

Comment: Is there another option? Or better option